# Raspberry Pi Alexa Echo Startup from Desktop

Tags: raspbian

No experience beyond novice Pi level, learning with interesting (to me) projects.

With little difficulty I have a Pi Echo working.

Pi Echo requires three separate terminal instances to run 3 separate series of commands:

#1 - cd ~/Desktop /Alexa-avs-sample-app/samples
      Cd companionService && npm start

#2 - cd ~/Desktop /Alexa-avs-sample-app/samples
      cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec

#3 - cd ~/Desktop /Alexa-avs-sample-app/samples
      cd wakewordAgent/STCR && ./wakewordAgent -e kitt_ai

I would like to put an icon on the desktop that runs the commands in three separate terminal windows that will STAY OPEN.

My research so far in creating desktop shortcuts has not provided me with results.

Very much appreciated.

Comment: I recently followed this tutorial. My understanding is that these need to be run in order, or in sequence basically. Login With Amazon is a manual step that must be performed in order to authenticate the client (corresponding to Alexa running on your device). I am looking for a way to do this in a headless manner; not sure if that is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

This works on Pi3

Create 3 shell scripts, one for each service.
[image]

I run this from the GUI (open in terminal) and works fine.
You still need to enter auth credentials though.
You will need to change paths - my files are all in Home/pi

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

For the launching of terminals you may have some success with a shell script using '-e' to execute your commands:

```
#! /bin/bash

LXTerminal -e "first command to run" &
LXTerminal -e "second command to run" &
LXTerminal -e "third command to run" &
```

For most terminals you can add a '-hold' to keep it open after the execution or specify it in the options for a profile. For LXTerminal I don't see an obvious way. A solution would be to install another terminal which has this option, xterm maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try - as well as a different terminal program.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of DAYS I found a way for a great autostart for Alexa and I wanted to post it for the others who are interested in this.
This autostart function is for the SamuelBrucksch Project. Thank you for the Project!

1. Create an empty file with the extension .sh and name it whatever you want.
   (For example: alexa-start.sh)
   Past the following Skript in the created File:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # First terminal
   lxterminal -l -e 'cd ~/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/companionService && npm start;' &

   # Wait
   sleep 10s

   # Second Terminal
   lxterminal -l -e 'cd ~/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient && mvn exec:exec;' &

   # Wait
   sleep 30s

   # Third terminal
   lxterminal -l -e 'cd ~/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/wakeWordAgent/src && ./wakeWordAgent -e kitt_ai;' &
   ```
2. Then, save the script file wherever you want, or in the */home/pi* folder like I did.
3. Give that file the necessary Permissions with: *chmod +x filename.sh*
4. Then, open */home/pi/.config/autostart* folder. It might be different in your 
   case. Just open your home folder and enable view hidden folders. If you don't 
   see the *autostart* folder, then create a folder called "autostart" within the 
   *.config* folder.
5. Within *autostart* folder you will need to create a shortcut to your script 
   file that you created as follows. Create an empty file with the extension 
   *.desktop*. (For example: "alexa-start.desktop")
6. Copy and paste the following in the empty *.desktop* file except you will need 
   to change *Comment, Name, Exec, Path and Icon* field's value (Actually you just 
   need to change the *Exec, Name, and Path* Values the others can stay as they 
   are:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Comment
   Exec=/path/to/Your/application/Name-of-the-script-file.sh
   Name=Name -of-the-script-file.sh
   Path=/Path/to/Your/application
   Type=Shell
   ```
7. Save and close the file after changing all the necessary fields. You are done. Just test it out and enjoy Alexa on your Raspberry!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this headless, kicking off three terminals I'd look into [crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot). Otherwise you should be able to run the script as a [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233529/run-bash-script-as-daemon). Remember that Raspbian is just Linux, and that you'll have luck in finding answers when googling by replacing Raspberry Pi with Linux.